# setting breakpoints in sass with min and max width

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass, media-queries, neat

Hey guys i am trying to work on a responsive layout but somehow i am not able to fix the min width for this one.

```
$mobile: new-breakpoint(max-width 480px 4);
$tablet: new-breakpoint(max-width 768px 8);
$desktop: new-breakpoint(max-width 1336px 10);
$desktopxl: new-breakpoint(max-width 1550px 10);
```

somehow i want the `$desktopxl` to be only used between `1337px` and `1550px`
But `i am not able to set the min width`. please help me.
thanks. ps: **i tried

```
 $desktopxl: new-breakpoint((max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px)10);
```

**But it didnt work.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need min and mix.
all you need is to do min next to max width.
like eg. if you max width is `700px` tour next level min width should be `701px`;

Try this

```
$mobile: new-breakpoint(max-width 480px 4);
$tablet: new-breakpoint(max-width 768px 8);
$desktop: new-breakpoint(min-width 779px 10);
$desktopxl: new-breakpoint(min-width 1337px 10);
```